# Find and Replacing a string with a numerical value in ragged array (Mathematica)

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica

I have a gaussian .cube file (http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/cube/) and am looking to find and replace any "NaN" string within this file with a numerical value. Importing my .cube file gives me a ragged array structure with both string and numerical values. I also have the option to import the file as a list of lists.

I have tried the ReplaceAll command, but Mathematica seems to be unable to find the NaN string to replace it. I defined my initial array as "cubefile":

```
newcubefile = cubefile /. "NaN" -> 1000000
```

The same goes for the ReplacePart command.

An example of a (shortened) .cube file with two NaN values I want to replace:

```
{" grad_cube", " 3d plot", " reduced density gradient", "   10    \
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000", "   45    0.711111    0.000000    \
0.000000", "   45    0.000000    0.711111    0.000000", "   45    \
0.000000    0.000000    0.711111", "   6  0.0   0.000000   0.000000   \
0.000000", "   8  0.0   0.636571  29.627942  31.998664", "   1  0.0   \
2.452233  29.435574  31.997116", "   8  0.0   1.419780   1.757082  \
31.998335", "   1  0.0  29.967743   0.233347   0.002315", "   1  0.0  \
 4.896759   1.786080  31.998626", "   8  0.0   6.712387   1.593495  \
31.999036", "   6  0.0   7.348967  31.221446  31.999373", "   8  0.0  \
 5.928984  29.464534  31.999015", "   1  0.0   9.381256  30.988384   \
0.000684", "  0.10000E+03  0.10000E+03  0.10000E+03  0.10888E+01  \
0.16636E+01  0.24435E+01", "  0.35378E+01  0.50957E+01  0.73141E+01  \
0.10460E+02  0.14902E+02  0.21154E+02", "  0.29923E+02  0.42194E+02  \
0.59323E+02  0.83185E+02  0.11637E+03  0.16246E+03", "  0.22639E+03  \
0.31515E+03  0.43757E+03  0.55223E+03  0.41025E+03  0.41014E+03", "  \
0.55221E+03  0.43755E+03  0.31514E+03  0.22639E+03  0.16245E+03  \
0.11637E+03", "  0.83184E+02  0.59323E+02  0.42194E+02  0.29924E+02  \
NaN NaN"}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Thank you all.

Comment: have you tried import as "Table"? Then i think your NaN's will show up as individual strings and the replace you tried will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   StringReplace[#, "NaN" -> "0.0"] & /@ list
```

where list is what you show above.

[image: Mathematica graphics]